# copy text files in different location and combine them to one text file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, text-processing

I need to concatenate text files in different locations to one textfile, preferably in batch or Powershell. How would this work?

Example:

```
copy
\\server1\f\tes1.txt
\\server2\f\test2.txt
\\server3\f\test3.txt
```

Destination:

```
\\server1\f\final.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
copy "\server1\f\tes1.txt" + "\server2\f\test2.txt" + "\server3\f\test3.txt" = "\server1\f\final.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

use + in copy command to concatenate multiple files into one file. Verified this in Windows 8 command prompt.

copy file1 + file2 + file3 destFile

For the files in question, the following should work

```
copy \server1\f\tes1.txt + \server2\f\test2.txt + \server3\f\test3.txt \server1\f\final.txt
```

Comment: for this you have to be very specific and name every file

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Content \\server1\f\tes1.txt,\\server2\f\test2.txt,\\server3\f\test3.txt | 
Out-File \\server1\f\final.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Change directory to your document folder and Run this command in cmd

```
forfiles /M *.act /C "cmd /c type @file >>d:\final.txt"
```

Where d:\final.txt is the output
*.act is the files with extension ACT

This command will pick every file from the Current directory with extension ACT and send it as Argument to CMD where that file content are echoed to final.txt

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the folder which contains all the server files

```
for /d %%a in (*) do type %%a\*.txt >> server1\final.txt
```

It should work

Comment: Which of the OP's folders is `*` in your code? Please clarify.

Comment: @Endoro I already said "Run this in the folder which contains all the server files" that is the folder which contains \server1\, \server2\ etc.

Comment: Server 1 2 and 3 are three different machines, in normal use.

Comment: The question does indeed specify that; look at the filenames.